# Find the directed subgraph with least edges that preserves connectivity

Tags: graphs, directed-graphs, subgraphs

I have a directed graph $G$ with a set of nodes $N$ and a set of edges $E$ with the following property : if $(A\to B)\in E$ and $(B\to C)\in E$, then $(A\to C)\in E$, for all nodes $A,B,C$.

I would like to find the subgraph $G'$ with the same set of nodes $N$ and a set of edges $E'$ such that:

1. The "connectivity" (not sure if this term can be used here) stays the same: if $(A\to B)\in E$, then there exists a path such that $\left(A\to N_1\right)\in E'$, $\left(N_1\to N_2\right)\in E'$, $\ldots$, $\left(N_p\to B\right)\in E'$
2. $\left|E'\right|$ is minimal

Is it a known/studied problem? What is the best algorithm to perform such a task? Is there a polynomial solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In mathematics and computer science, connectivity is one of the basic concepts of graph theory: it asks for the minimum number of elements (nodes or edges) that need to be removed to separate the remaining nodes into two or more isolated subgraphs", says [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29).

[Reachability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability) is the term that refers to the ability to get from one vertex to another  within a graph.

[A transitive reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) of a directed graph $G$ is another directed graph $G'$ with the same vertices as $G$ and with the fewest possible edges that has the same reachability relation as $G$.

---

Your problem is known as **finding the transitive reduction** of a given directed graph, with the condition that the given directed graph is its own transitive closure and with the catch that the transitive reduction $G'$ must be a subgraph, i.e., every edge in $G'$ is also an edge of $G$.

An characterization of $G'$ is also given in [that Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction#In_graphs_with_cycles).
Since your graph $G$ is its own transitive closure, each strongly connected component of it is, in fact, a complete directed graph. So it is trivial to find "a directed cycle for each strongly connected component of $G$, connecting together the vertices in this component", with all edges in $G$. So we can always construct the transitive reduction as a subgraph of $G$. So, your problem is, indeed, equivalent to finding the transitive reduction of a transitively-closed directed graph.

---

The characterization of $G'$ also indicates how to find it in **linear-time** as below.

1. Compute the condensation of $G$ using any one of [the linear-time algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#Algorithms). (We can make this step much easier, since $G$ is transitively closed.)
2. Select the edges of the transitive reduction that correspond to condensation of $G$, an acyclic graph.
3. For each strongly connected component of $G$, which is a complete directed graph, select a listing of all nodes in it as a cycle.
4. Return all edges selected in step 2 and 3.